# SQL: Display multiple record values in one field from a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL LIKE:

```
SELECT S.*, 
   (SELECT I.NAME FROM institution I, inst_map IM 
           WHERE IM.STUDENT = S.ID AND IM.INSTITUTION = I.ID) as INSTITUTIONS 
FROM student S
```

In this case it is possible for my subquery to return multiple records (I will get an error: `Subquery returns more than 1 row`).

How to show those multiple values from my subquery in one field (in my case `INSTITUTIONS` ) separated by commas?

All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT s.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.NAME) INSTITUTIONS FROM student s
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM institution i
              JOIN inst_map im
                ON im.INSTITUTION = i.ID
             ) t
  ON s.ID = t.STUDENT
GROUP BY s.ID
```

The [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function will help you to get values separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(5000)
SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ' + Display, Display)
FROM TestTable
Order By Display
```

query is taken from following link, and the article explain the query perfectly, I hope it works
http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/289/creating-comma-separated-list-in-sql.aspx

P.S Its for SQL Server, i guess